# Не работает delete_message

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет! Пишу бота на python, при помощи библиотеки aiogram, и такая проблема:

У меня есть меню, которое отвечает за всю навигацию и вот, при определенном нажатии, у меня выходит фото с подписью, и когда я выхожу на главное меню, мне надо, чтобы это фото удалялось, то есть следующее сообщение.

При вызове метода `bot.delete_message(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=current_menu[chat_id]['message_id']+1)`, то есть удаление следующего сообщения у меня это фото удаляется, но, когда я повторяю данную процедуру, у меня execept выдает ошибку: `Message to delete not found`.
В чем дело?

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: True)
async def process_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    menu_key = callback_query.data
    chat_id = callback_query.message.chat.id
    print("menu_key:",menu_key)
    if menu_key == 'back':
        # Получаем предыдущее меню из словаря current_menu
        previous_menu = current_menu[chat_id]['previous_menu']
        if previous_menu:
            # Обновляем текущее меню
            current_menu[chat_id]['menu_key'] = previous_menu
            # Отображаем предыдущее меню
            await dm.display_menu(chat_id, previous_menu)
    if menu_key == 'menu_main':
        try:
            message = await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id, "typing")
            if message:
                await bot.delete_message(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=current_menu[chat_id]['message_id']+1)
            else:
                print("Сообщение не найдено")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Ошибка при получении сообщения:", e)

        await dm.display_menu(chat_id, menu_key)
```